# Adding to object with dot notation not working in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, express, mongoose

I have the strangest problem in Mongoose. I have the following object:

```
        var gameInfo = { "id": $scope.gamedata._id, "role": role, "equipment": "", "notes": "" };
```

I use Node to send this to the following function:

```
app.put('/userJoin/:userid', function (req, res) {
    console.log("app user join data: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var userid = req.params.userid;
    var u_id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid);
    var query = { _id: u_id };
    User.findOne(query).exec(function (err, tempuser) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tempuser));
        if (tempuser.games == null) {
            console.log("creating games list");
            tempuser.games = [req.body];
            tempuser.x = 5;
            tempuser.shoes = "red";
            console.log("created games list");
        }
        else {
            console.log("adding to games list");
            tempuser.games.push(req.body);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tempuser));
        tempuser.save(function (err) {
            if (err) { res.send(err); }
            else { res.status(200).end(); }
        });
    });
});
```

In it, I retrieve a user from my database with `User.findone(query)` and, since it does not yet have the property games, the `if` block fires and I see `creating games list` and `created games list` in my console. However, I also use the console to check before and after the `if` block and the `tempuser` object has not changed at all. Since I check before and after I am pretty much certain the fault must be within the `if` block but I can not figure out why.

EDIT: For clarification purposes, this is the output of the server side console:

```
app user join data: {"id":"56e06bf57b05ae040e4227ae","role":"2","equipment":"","notes":""}
{"_id":"56e84cce39f024241eaa0b7f","__v":0,"password":"03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f034","username":"a"}
creating games list
created games list
{"_id":"56e84cce39f024241eaa0b7f","__v":0,"password":"03c7c0ace395d80182db07ae2c30f034","username":"a"}
```

As you can see, despite adding three more properties to tempuser with dot notation, nothing has been added to it.

Comment: This question appears to be about Javascript and Mongoose, not about Express at all.  I'd suggest modifying the title and tags to reflect that and to perhaps attract people to the question that know something about mongoose.

Comment: Please show the exact  `console.log()` output you get when you run this.

Comment: I could not fully understand the problem! What is not working with dot notation?

Comment: jfriend00, I have edited the tags and title, thank you. I have also added the console log.

Answer (score 0):

After a brisk walk the answer popped into my head and I have verified it to be correct. The problem lay in my lack of understanding some Mongoose basics, being new to the framework.

`User.findOne(query).exec(function (err, tempuser)` retrieves a Mongoose Model, not a plain javascript object, and as I realized, Models cannot be directly altered after creation (only their values can be updated). The `games:[]` array was not part of the Model and I could therefore not add it.